# In Scala, why 'case object' and not just 'object'?

Tags: scala, akka

I read and understand, `case class` is to send arguments and create multiple object and `case object` don't send any arguments and having single object. So that will achieve by `object` also why `case object`.

Why is `case object` important and when? I already gone through this post, but I did not get why `case object`.

[Difference between case class and case object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078526/difference-between-case-class-and-case-object)

Comment: I gone through that post, I not cleared my doubt so i posted. Kindly help me if you can.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Answers in that question do not address the real question of OP and that is importance of `case` in a `case object`.

Comment: @Sarvesh But the said duplicate provides exactly the different semantics when adding `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Well... an `object` in `Scala` can be `"roughly"` explained as an instance of an `anonymous class`. Now the difference in a `case object` and `object` lies in the difference of that `anonymous class` being a `case class` or just a `class`

To put it more clearly,

```
object A

// is roughly equivalent to something like

class AnonymousClass12345
val A = new AnonymousClass12345()
```

Where as for `case object`,

```
case object A

// is roughly equivalent to something like,

case class AnonymousClass12345
val A = new AnonymousClass12345()
```

And now it should be very easy to relate to `case class` vs `class`. And as an instance of an `anonymous case class`, `case object` gets all the goodies that any instance of any other `case class` does.

Note :: This answer is meant to provide an inaccurate but easy to understand explanation. A more accurate answer of this question will require not only an understanding of the difference `class vs type` which is nicely (but not very accurately) discussed in this - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5036087/1151929) but also of Scala reflection.

Comment: `object A` is an instance of `A.type`, not an "anonymous class".

Comment: In simple words, **case** mean immutable, am I right?

Comment: NO... as big NO. `case class` or `case object` have nothing to do with `immutability`

Comment: @mikołak Well... I suppose you did not noticed `roughly` in `is roughly equivalent to something like`. Or are you ready to explain `what A.type is ?` to a Scala beginner like OP ? Edited the answer to emphasise more on `roughly`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: 1. Moslty I noticed "is nothing but" at the very start of the original revision (now edited, thank you). 2. Yeah, sure, how does e.g. _`A` is an instance of an automatically generated "class" `A.type`_  sound?

Comment: that `"class"`... :P